# where can I find a really good tutorial to create 3d carousel in flash MX?

Tags: flash

where can I find a really good tutorial to create 3d carousel in flash MX? has anyone implemented this in flash MX?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code for Lee Brimelow's carousel:

http://gotoandlearn.com/files/carousel3.zip

Here is a tutorial based on the code:

http://flash.lillegutt.com/?p=14

Both use ActionScript 2 and can be created in MX.